# How to use a CookieCollection in multiple functions

Tags: cakephp, cookies, cakephp-3.7

I'm setting up a web page using cookies to determine if the user already logged in, using a cookie containing his id. Problem is : The cookie is either not written or the cookie collection is not updated.

I've tried reading the documentation, but it does not define the usage of CookieCollection.

Here's the function where i write my cookie :

```php
function displayData(){
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getSession()->read('id');
        $cookies = CookieCollection::createFromServerRequest($this->getRequest());
        if(!$cookies->has('id')){
            $cookie = (new Cookie('id'))
                ->withValue($id)
                ->withExpiry(new DateTime('+999 year'))
                ->withPath('/')
                ->withDomain('break-first.eu')
                ->withSecure(true)
                ->withHttpOnly(true);
            $cookies = $cookies->add($cookie);
        }
        // Other stuff
    }
```

And where I try reading it :

```php
function index(){
        $cookies = $this->getRequest()->getCookieCollection();
        dd($cookies);
    }
```

I expect having a cookie named "id", but I don't have it. Only CAKEPHP and pll_language are showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, CakePHP provides authentication functionality with cookie authentication, you may want to have a look at that instead of driving a custom solution.

- **[Cookbook > Plugins > Authentication](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/index.html)**

That being said, what you're doing there will create a cookie collection object, which however is just that, a lone object somewhere in space, it won't affect the state of your application, in order for that to happen you have to actually modify the response object.

However what you're trying to do there doesn't require cookie collections in the first place, you can simply read and write cookies directly via the methods provided by the request and response objects, like:

```
// will be `null` in case the cookie doesn't exist
$cookie = $this->getRequest()->getCookie('id');
```

```
// responses are immutable, they need to be reassinged
this->setResponse(
    $this->getResponse()->withCookie(
        (new Cookie('id'))
            ->withValue($id)
            ->withExpiry(new DateTime('+999 year'))
            ->withPath('/')
            ->withDomain('break-first.eu')
            ->withSecure(true)
            ->withHttpOnly(true)
    )
);
```

And if you where to use a cookie collection for whatever reason, then you'd use `withCookieCollection()` to pass it into the response:

```
$this->setResponse($this->getResponse()->withCookieCollection($cookies));
```

If you run into [**strict typing errors**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/12933), you could for example create a custom reponse class with an overridden `Response::convertCookieToArray()` method and cast the string to an integer there (make sure that `PHP_INT_MAX` covers your target date timestamp, 32-Bit incompatibility is why the fix that landed in CakePHP 4.x, probably won't come to 3.x), something like:

**src/Http/Response.php**

```
namespace App\Http;

use Cake\Http\Cookie\CookieInterface;
use Cake\Http\Response as CakeResponse;

class Response extends CakeResponse
{
    protected function convertCookieToArray(CookieInterface $cookie)
    {
        $data = parent::convertCookieToArray($cookie);
        $data['expire'] = (int)$data['expire'];

        return $data;
    }
}
```

You can pass that into the app in your `webroot/index.php` file, as the second argument of the `$server->run()` call:

```
// ...
$server->emit($server->run(null, new \App\Http\Response()));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Request > Cookies](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cookies)**
- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Response > Setting Cookies](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-cookies)**

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
However, it seems that it is not working, as i now have a warning : "Warning (2): setcookie() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given [CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 210]"
Where could that come from ? (I used the solution without the CookieCollection)

Edit : I'll take a look at Auth later on, thanks.

Comment: @Baka [**That's kind of a PHP bug**](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76755), which has been fixed/changed as of 7.3.0. You can workaround that by passing the expiry value as an integer (I've updated the example). CakePHP 4 will convert date objects to integers (**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/12933**), this will probably not come to CakePHP 3.x because of possible problems with large integers on 32-bit systems.

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll come back to you when the boss will have updated php to 7.3.0.

Comment: @Baka I wouldn't rely on the behavior that a string is being accepted, because strictly speaking that's wrong according to the function's signature, even accepting a float as in the bug report is IMHO wrong. Using an integer is the way to go if you ask me.

Comment: Will definitely try that out, thanks for your reply !

Comment: "Call to a member function setTimezone() on integer" is what I'm getting now, any idea where that could come from ?

Comment: @Baka Ugh... sorry, looks like the cookie class expects you to pass a datetime object... oh boy, well, you could use a custom response and overwrite `Response::convertCookieToArray()` and cast the string to an integer there.

Comment: Oh wait, maybe the problem came from the "+999 years", as with "+10 years" it's working. Well, thank you a lot for helping me through this, have a wonderful day!